# Pulling from local registry gives UNAUTHORIZED

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am running a Docker registry in a container which I run as-is from the image of 'docker-registry', as published on Docker hub. This image is running on a machine in my local network. From my laptop I am able to push an image to that registry without any problems. I subsequently try to pull that same image to a different machine on my network, but there I get an error response:
`{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required", ...}`
This raises the questions: Is this image configured to require authentication? Why does it not require authentication when I push/pull from my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason could be that the target machine where you are trying to run your docker image does not have root/sudo access. This is generally an issue with docker. It does require root privileges. Try to ensure required permission is given when you run your docker commands. (Try using sudo with commands)

Can't be very sure of the reason, need more info regarding the machine where you are running the docker.

Comment: Appreciate the tip. However I have done everything on that machine under the root account. Mind you I am able to pull from / push to this registry from my laptop.